# Android java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

I know this has been asked a lot on SO, but unfortunately none of the answers did solve my problem.

I have 3 Android devices for testing + emulator and my app just works fine on all of them, but when I publish the app I get this error (only on few devices, not all):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{<package>/<package>.<ProjectName>Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <package>.MainSurfaceView
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <package>.MainSurfaceView
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
 at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
 at <package>.<ProjectName>Activity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
 ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <package>.MainSurfaceView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/<package>-1.apk]
 at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
```

The class extends class GLSurfaceView and has 3 constructors (GLSurfaceView supports only 2, but I read on SO that the missing third may cause the problem - it doesn't).

Class (only constructors):

```java
public class MainSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public MainSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MainSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MainSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Adding constructor

```java
public MainSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

did not solve the problem.

My manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="<package>"
      android:versionCode="5"
      android:versionName="1.2.1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:anyDensity="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:resizeable="true" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".<project>Activity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

And my layout file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="480dp"
  android:layout_height="800dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center">

    <<package>.MainSurfaceView android:id="@+id/glSurface" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="top|left"/>

  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="<id>"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks for any help. It would be also very helpful if someone can tell me how to recreate the error.

Comment: It happend to my published apps too, even with an Activity class.I think that some phones just have bugs or have to be rebooted.

Comment: K-ballo: Yes, I use ProGuard;
VinceFR: The problem also occures on Android 2.3.5 (I don't know if it's an official release), but the amazon team refuses to publish my app just beacause it doesn't work on 2.3.5

Comment: @cleanac: If you have updated to _ADTv17_ or above, the old _ProGuard_ files will do this to you. Create a new empty project, and see _project.properties_ and _proguard-properties_ and modify your current project accordingly.

Comment: @K-ballo: With your help I could finally recreate the error and fix it. Thank you. I think it would be nice if you write an answer so I can accept it as the sollution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have updated to *ADTv17* or above, the old *ProGuard* files will do this to you. Create a new empty project, and see *project.properties* and *proguard-properties* and modify your current project accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use try catch block for finding the exact error. On my case, I also found "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException". After I debug it, it is caught on in catch block. It show "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment". Thus, when we get error as above, we need to debug it first to find the exact error.